# Capybara is not starting its own server with js: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, tdd, capybara

I am trying to start writing test on my application but I am having problems with `js: true` This is not starting its own server.

Envirormetals

```
 rails -v #Rails 5.2.0
 ruby -v ruby 2.4.2p198
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'capybara'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

I followed the configuration on this tutorial
https://www.devmynd.com/blog/setting-up-rspec-and-capybara-in-rails-5-for-testing/

I know its not starting its owe server because this is the error I get

```
Failures:

  1) Login
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content("Sarah")
       expected to find text "Sarah" in "This site can’t be reached\nlocalhost refused to connect.\nTry:\nChecking the connection\nChecking the proxy and the firewall\nERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED\nReload\nDETAILS"
     # ./spec/helpers/login.rb:9:in `login_user'
```

This is what is in the # ./spec/helpers/login.rb:9:in `login_user' file

```
require "rails_helper"
  RSpec.feature "Financial Profile", :type => :feature do

    scenario "just login", js: true do
      login_user
    end

    def login_user
      user = FactoryBot.create(:user, email: 'sconnor@myfefa.com', name: 'Sarah Connor')
      login_as(user, :scope => :user, :run_callbacks => false)
      visit root_path
      expect(page).to have_content("Sarah")
      expect(page).to have_link("Logout")
    end
  end
```

Now this works perfect if I make it

```
    scenario "just login", js: false do
      login_user
    end
```

Comment: What makes you think it's not starting its own server? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Also, if you're actually using Rails 5.2 that tutorial is out of date because you don't need database_cleaner anymore and you do want to leave transactional tests enabled.

Comment: do you know of a article or tutorial that better explains how to set up `capybara` with `selenium-webdriver`? I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: There really isn't much to setup (in a basic config) beyond setting `Capybara.javascript_driver` and including the files mentioned in the Capybara README - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#setup.  Add any Capybara and RSpec configuration you have set to your question.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole you're not quite right. Because if you use `js: true` the test is run in a separate thread and the JS driver doesn't share the same connection with the database. In general, reading this article is very good idea: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-we-test-rails-applications

Comment: @double_u1 Actually I am correct.  The article you linked to was originally written over 7 years ago, and things have changed a lot since then -- Nowadays most people can run their tests in transactional mode and the DB connection will be shared between the app and test thread (Rails will check the one connection in and out of the pool to the application and test code as needed) and be quite a bit faster.  Database cleaner is not required for most projects.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole of course the article was updated in 2019 ;) And since it is maintained by #thoughtbot I assume the contents are up-to-date. 

The information actually came from (yet another "2014" article): https://thoughtbot.com/blog/write-reliable-asynchronous-integration-tests-with-capybara which clearly explains why JS & Ajax is difficult in testing

Comment: @double_u1 Yes - the article was updated in 2019 - but was still aimed at older projects - it is not up-to-date.  When Rails 5.1 was released it added the shared DB connection for system tests - which obviated the need for database cleaner, etc in most projects (for both system tests and system/feature specs) - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html#system-tests.  -  I write Capybara, so I do understand all the nuances around this and my posted information is correct. As for the second article you posted, that's also out-of-date - `first(".active").click` is fine to use now, etc